# How to ensure colcon does not run doxygen

Tags: colcon

I noticed upon building Gazebo Garden that it runs doxygen. This takes a significant time. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `colcon` option, but Gazebo libraries have a cmake flag for disabling documentation. You'd pass it through colcon via `--cmake-args -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF`. [This](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-cmake/blob/gz-cmake3/tutorials/developing_with_gz-cmake.md) is a good tutorial to look through for this and other flags.